# Importing Excel data into SQL Server and converting to DateTime

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime

guys,

I've got some datetime data in an Excel file, formatted appropriately for SQL Server datetime conversion (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:000). Unfortunately, when I try to import the data into an SQL field of type DateTime, I get these error messages:

```
Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "Datetime" (27) to column "Datetime" (60).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Datetime]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Datetime]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion 0 - 0" (52) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (53). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - Sheet2$ returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I specifically have to import from Excel and not from CSV because there is Hebrew text in the source file which SQL Server refuses to recognize with any of the encodings available in CSV import.

`

Comment: Datetime (27)  & Datatime (60) appear to be separate formats. Try changing the excel column to a custom format date that matches your sql date format which depends on your language setting.

Comment: The excel column's format is currently a custom DateTime: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000. What should I change it to?

Comment: You may want to try a period instead of a colon between ss and 000. If you still can't get it working, maybe try importing as a string instead then using cast() post import.

Comment: That was on the right track-deleted milliseconds entirely and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked was deleting the milliseconds entirely.